# Changing file name with its directory name in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I am trying to recursively change some file names according to their directory name but I am failed. Here is what I have done so far:

```
for /r %1 %%Z in (*.c) do (
    echo ====
    rem Change to the directory of .c file
    echo cd /d "%%~dpZ"
    cd /d "%%~dpZ"
    rem Change the file's name with its directory name with .c extension        
    ren %%~nxZ %cd%.c
)
```

And here is the directory structure:

```
SubDir
    renamer.bat
    sub1
         file1.c
    sub2
         file2.c
   so on
         so forth
```

All the other posts say that using `%cd%` returns the current directory's name, however it returns something like that: `c:\users\myusername\desktop\SubDir`,means it returns the batch file's directory name. However, as you can see, I use `cd` command in the batch file, so I want it to returns **only** `sub1`, `sub2`, etc... Thus, I can able to change the file names into their directory's name:

```
ren file1.c sub1.c
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Answer

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r %1 %%Z in (*.c) do (
    echo ====
    rem Change to the directory of .c file
    echo cd /d "%%~dpZ"
    cd /d "%%~dpZ"
    rem Change the file's name with its directory name with .c extension  
    FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%%~dpZ\.") DO (ren %%~nxZ %%~nxa.c)
)
```

Comment: Please do not provide a solution by editing the question, post it as an answer because that is what it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%%~dpZ\.") DO ECHO(ren %%~nxZ %%~nxa-%%~nxZ
```

to `echo` the new name....

Answer (score 0):

You should use delayed expansion in this case. You should use this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r %1 %%Z in (*.c) do (
    echo ====
    rem Change to the directory of .c file
    echo cd /d "%%~dpZ"
    cd /d "%%~dpZ"
    rem Change the file's name with its directory name with .c extension  
    for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!CD!") do ren "%%~nxZ" "%%~nxA.c"
)
```

For more information about delayed expansion, see [this](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: It still applies wrong command. `ren file1.c c:\bla bla\sub1.c` I need `ren file1.c sub1.c`

Comment: `The system cannot find the file C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\SubDir\sub1.` says. still dont work.

Comment: @WhoCares did you use the quotes around `!CD!`?

Comment: Directly copied what you told. So yes.

Comment: Can you try placing `echo` before `ren` and tell me what the output is? I also edited the quotes in later, that's why I asked.

Comment: It worked with Magoo's reply. But I want to accept your answer for your effort. Just change the relevant line with his.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @WhoCares As his answer solved your problem you should accept his. You are free ofcourse, to upvote mine if you feel this is appropriate.